# DNS Map sub domain to another sub domain, which records?

Tags: redirect, dns, routes, mask, cname

I have a master domain name:

```
exampledev.co.uk
```

and an administration panel at:

```
admin.exampledev.co.uk
```

We then have a client:

```
exampleclient.co.uk
```

What I want to do is, map a subdomain:

```
admin.exampleclient.co.uk
```

to

```
admin.exampledev.co.uk
```

All of these sites will be stored on the same server. The idea is that on `admin.exampledev.co.uk`, it will use the HTTP_HOST variable to determine which admin database to load.

Which DNS record do I change to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a CNAME record on admin.exampleclient.co.uk to point to admin.exampledev.co.uk.

Comment: I have tried that but when I load admin.exampleclient.co.uk, it loads the contents of exampledev.co.uk not admin.exampledev.co.uk

Comment: Was this FQDN pointed to the root of exampledev.co.uk at one point? If so, I'd chalk it up to a caching issue. Otherwise, there may be a virtualhost setting in your web server configuration that is shunting requests to the root.